# loaded nib not updating frame size

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nib

I'm having issues resizing view loaded through loadNibNamed, their frame its updated when instantiated and only get the set size when I go to another view and go back.

The flow its:

- viewDidLoad
- loadNibNamed
- set the corresponding frame
- add the nib to main view (wrong size here, its the same from the nib file)
- go forward to another view
- go back (size its shown correctly)
- :sad:

The code I use to instantiate the nib its:

```
class NibView: UIView {
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup("xibName")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup("xibName")
    }

  func xibSetup(name: String) {
        view = loadViewFromNib(name)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.frame.size = bounds.size

        addSubview(view)

  func loadViewFromNib(name: String) -> UIView {
        let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(name, owner: self, options: nil)
        let view = nib[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `xibSetup` from the init method. `bounds.size` is not set yet, but you are using it to set the `view.frame.size`.